# npm run <command> not working

Tags: npm

With a package.json file like:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "hello": "touch hello && echo hello"
    }
}
```

Running `npm run hello` creates no file and outputs nothing to stdout.  I was expecting both to happen.

npm -v  # 4.4.0

Comment: How did you install npm (brew, macports, etc.)?

Comment: @MattS installed using .pkg from https://nodejs.org/en/download/  I recall I had some problem with the brew install when I tried it before.

Comment: I think something is screwed with your installation of npm. It's strange, however, that `npm -v` works. Does npm work fine in every other aspect? Try renaming your script to `test` and running `npm test`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ignore-scripts=true` was set in .npmrc

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10675

Comment: Thanks, Helped out today had to find .npmrc in my files and set it to **false**  `ignore-scripts=false`

Comment: Thanks, I was following the advice on this video to set it to true to avoid viruses https://youtu.be/24tQRwIRP_w?t=1001 , I didn't make the connection initially, but setting it back to false as follows fixes the issue for me: npm config set ignore-scripts false